# HTTPS request using python requests library

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I am trying to send a https request using python requests library
my code is

```
full_url = ''.join(['https://', get_current_site(request).domain, '/am/reply'])
data = {'agent_type':'trigger','input':platform,'user':request.user.id}
print  "hi" ### this is printing
a = requests.get(full_url,params=data,verify=False) ##the execution is stucked here even error are not appearing 
print "hello" ## this code is not printed
```

The problem is that there is no execution after requests whole code is stucked at this point.
I tried to verify my code using python shell and it run perfectly.
Is there any way that i can debug whole my requests response that is going on real time or can someone suggest me a solution

The whole code was working fine when there was http but after switching to https whole code stopped working. I even tried to place the certificate file but also no success

Comment: what kind of output you are expecting?

Comment: @JitendraMeena at the last line of code my execution is getting stucked means not even the errors are being displayed ...but using python shell i can execute the code

Comment: it's working fine... the print the output .. you should do something like this
print(a.json()) or print(a.content)

Comment: can you share the domain name of your website?

Comment: @JitendraMeena https://facebook.tuple-mia.com:8000/am/reply/

Comment: you are not passing slack_user... you should try this in try and except block
data = {'agent_type':'trigger','input':platform,'slack_user':request.user.id}

Comment: @JitendraMeena  now try i have removed all useless code

Comment: it says "hi"...

Comment: yes i have changed it but still not getting responses from requests..

Comment: can you share view code

Comment: i already shared it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138809/discussion-between-jitendra-meena-and-user3411846).

Answer (score 0):

It is normal. Some website only accept `http` and some `https` and some of them both. http port is 80 and https port is port 443. For example, if a website is using https which means is secure http. So they actually need extra information in header etc. 
 Check requests api for http
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Comment: Do you have to use https? I mean if http request  are working then continue with it.

Comment: If possible can you add url to your question?  So we can control it

Comment: the code is working on regular https ie on port 443 but its not working on django runsslserver confgiuration

Comment: maybe it is affected by verify=False option

Comment: no its working only with verify=False as i am not passing any certificate to it

Comment: I think the problem maybe related to django ssl server.